# Eclipse formatter/clean-up downfalls

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I aggressively use Eclipse formatter and clean-up for all my code. Every time I save my source, all my code is formatted nicely, indentation fixed, braces put in correct places and removed where unnecessary, imports are organized, variables declared final where they should be, and other fine little things happen.

It's very comfortable to user, but I'm just curious – are there any drawbacks? May be bad habits that I'll acquire unknowingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reformatting can play havoc with diffs in version control.

If there are multiple developers then make sure formatting is done to a common standard. Agree on a standard, export the formatting rules from Eclipse and put the formatting rules into source control somewhere. Get all devs to check out the rules and apply them.

Better still, use a version control hook to automatically format all source to the standard rules as part of the commit. This way *you will never have to use Ctrl-Shift-f again!

Comment: I have to agree with this. I have been in situations where two developers have different formatting rules and it just gets messy. Agreeing on a single format keeps the source code clean and consistently formatted.

Comment: I'm currently working on a project alone, but of course I turn formatter of for open-source projects I occasionally commit to.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, the default rules work well.  Are you using default values?  Are you the lone developer or walking into an existing team / project?

The format and cleanup rules can be altered, tailored, and saved right alongside your source code. In essence, what my format button does may not be the same as what your format button does if either of us moved from the default rules.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I've seen is on mutil-member teams, if you do not share the same formatting rules, the formatting can result in difficulty comparing changes before check-in. So, for example, if you have a clean check-out then make a small change to ten files then use the synchronize view to compare your changes before check-in, all the spacing changes can obstruct the actual changes you have made. This can, for example, make a code review more difficult.